# Polynomial Ring and Prime Ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A=k[X], k$ a field. I am reading in a Algebra book that the ideal $(m)$ of all polynomials in $A$ with zero constant term is maximal. At the other hand, since $(m)$ is principal ideal, all polynomials in $(m)$ will have zero constant term. But having zero constant term means that $m$ is not irreducible ( one can factorize $X$ ) and thus not prime. Here I have a conflict since a maximal ideal is a prime one.

Can somebody help me understand what is here wrong ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't factor an $X$ from the polynomial $X$ itself, though (well, you *can*, but not in the sense of the element being reducible). And $X\in k[X]$ is exactly the element which generates the maximal ideal of polynomials with zero constant term.

Comment: Many thanks. Why is $(m)$ maximal ? Can we say that in the case of $A$, where $k$ is a field, $m$ irreducible $\Leftrightarrow$ $m$ prime ?

Comment: @user249018 The ideal of polynomials with no constant term, which generated by $X$, and therefore usually denoted $(X)$ rather than $(m)$, is maximal because $k[X]/(X)\cong k$ is a field.

Comment: Thats right. Does the assertion in the second question hold ?

Comment: @user249018 In a unique factorisation domain (such as the ring of polynomials over a field), irreducible and prime are equivalent. So $m$ irreducible $\Leftrightarrow$ $m$ prime $\Leftrightarrow$ $(m)$ is a prime ideal.